# Printing google maps with numbered markers

Tags: google-maps

Link to the map : http://2dynamic.com.au/glebe/maps-aamp-guides.html

In the above link we have dynamic markers in maps view. When I click on the print current map view I need the map to be loaded with dynamically numbered markers. I hope it is possible to make it.

Better if someone can show some coding example.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own LabeledMarker class which inherits from Marker. [This](http://www.googlemapsbook.com/2007/01/22/extending-gmarker/) is a really good tutorial that I used to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to what [Alex suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070915/i-am-new-to-google-maps-need-some-help-in-printing-the-google-maps-with-numbered/3083045#3083045) may be to use a set of numbered icons, such as one of the sets provided at the following site:

- [Google Marker Icons](http://jg.org/mapping/icons.html)

Then you should be able to do the following (using the v3 API):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Demo</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];

      var image;

      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker' + i + '.png',
                                            new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                                            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                            new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          title: location[0],
          zIndex: location[3]
        });
      }
    }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize();"> 
    <div id="map" style="width:400px; height:500px;"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot from the above example:

[Google Numbered Marker Icons http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3433/nummap.png](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3433/nummap.png)

Note that you can easily add a shadow behind the markers. You may want to check the example at the [Google Maps API Reference: Complex Markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#ComplexIcons) for more info about this.

Porting this example to the v2 API should be quite straight forward. Let me know if you would need assistance with this.